# How to filter only the date from a string stored in a varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ii have values stored in the SQL Server in the following manner : `02-Jul-12 12:00:00 AM` here the time and minutes, seconds can be anything like `02-Jul-12 12:15:52 PM` ,`02-Jul-12 6:02:12 AM` so on.

I want to have a where condition which will omit the time and take the data based on the date like the following `where some_Date='02-Jul-12'`

How would I do this?

Comment: You should not use string-paramaters for `datetime` fields.

Comment: the data stored in SQL Server is in a varchar (or other character based) field? There's your problem. Store date/times in a datetime field.

Comment: Is the data type actually a char/varchar, or a datetime?

Comment: if its varchar and you don't want to change it to date, use LIKE... I've put the SQL in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE some_Date LIKE '02-Jul-12%';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_MyTable
    WHERE 
 REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), DateTimeValueColumn, 6), ' ', '-')='02-Jul-12'
```

or

On chage in code is instead of using getdate function voncert you datestring in datetime format and do compare this follow query will work for you

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_MyTable
WHERE 
CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), DateTimeValueColumn, 102) AS DATE) = 
            CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10),GETDATE(),102) AS DATE)
```

Comment: Pranay Rana i have not down voted your answer. I always thank for the efforts made to answer. When down voting people should give reason for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on SQL2008 or later, you can cast your `DATETIME` to `DATE`.

See this post: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/09/12/sql-server-get-date-and-time-from-current-datetime-sql-in-sixty-seconds-025-video/

But in a WHERE-clause it is better to search between dates, like this:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '02-Jul-2012'
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startDate)

SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [some_Date] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing dates as characters -- which is not recommended -- you should at least use ISO format:  YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.  This makes the date useful for sorting and comparisons ("<" works, ">" works, "between" works as well as equals).

To extract the date, you can then use `left(datestr, 10)`.  In your format, you would use:

```
where left(datestr, 9) = '01-Jan-13'
```

If you are storing the fields as a `datetime` or `smalldatetime`, you may think they are stored as a string.  They are not.  They are stored as some number of days since some particular date, with day parts stored as fractional days.  If you are using SQL Server 2005 or greater, then the best way is:

```
where cast(datetime as date) = '2013-01-01'  -- I recommend ISO formats, even for constants.  '20130101' is even better
```

Answer (score 1):

To select rows with today's date (not time)

```
select * from myTable where datediff(dd, dateColumn, getdate()) = 0
```

Comment: OP has mentioned that the "date" field is of type `varchar`.

Comment: This works fine with varchar (when dates are formatted in OP)